# Understanding sentence (at odds; critical standing)

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence-meaning

> But Mendelssohn’s
> enduring popularity has often been `at odds` — sometimes quite sharply — with his `critical standing`.

What do `at odds` and `critical standing` mean in the above sentence?

Comment: At odds means in contrast to, fighting, an enemy of. Critical Standing is how fancy art critics see the individual. People say yes, while the experts say yes and no.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin It isn't just 'fancy art critics' (or fancy music critics) who find his music conventional and conservative. His church music, like "Oh For the Wings of a Dove" - hugely popular in England in Victorian times - is as schmaltzy and sanctimonious as it gets.